# iphone notification

Tags: iphone, notifications

how to send notification from one iphone device to another without paying single penny
pls provide some code for such "push notification"

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly send the push notification like this. Read the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) and get the clear idea of how push notification works.